# IAM user policy to RW to specific folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, cloudberry

I am trying out CloudBerry Drive tool to attach S3 buckets as my network drive. I have a bucket and 2 folders inside that, assuming the bucket name as environment and 2 folders as dev and prod. I have 3 sets of users who would use this - Admin, Dev and Prod.
Admin - Must have R/W permissions to both the folders.
Dev - Should have Write access only to dev folder
Prod - Should have Read access to dev folder and Write access to prod folder.

However I am confused with IAM permissions. Admin works fine with the S3 Full Access Permissions. But the other 2 accounts are not working fine.

**Dev**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:RestoreObject",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::environment/dev/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this I should be able to R/W to the dev folder, which I am unable to do. Using CloudBerry Drive I can copy paste a file, but not getting uploaded to S3. Also, the files in S3 are listed here (which is required) but can't access the same (Error attached).

**Prod**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:ReplicateTags",
            "s3:RestoreObject",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ReplicateDelete",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::environment/Prod"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this I should be able to R/W to the prod folder, which I am unable to do. Using CloudBerry Drive I can copy paste a file, but not getting uploaded to S3.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::environment"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "dev/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

The files in S3 are listed here (which is required) but can't access the same (Error attached).

Hope I am clear about my requirement:
1. dev user to have R/W access to dev folder only
2. prod user to have R/W access to prod folder and R access to dev folder
3. All these are done using CloudBerry Drive for S3.

Note: I have googled a lot and tried almost everything, including some policies which shows how to provide write permission to a specific user folder.
[image]

Comment: S3 doesn't actually have folders. The console simulates them, but it's just based off `/` characters in your objects' keys. Why not use separate buckets for dev/prod? Much safer and easier.

Comment: @ceejayoz: The customer requires that for some purpose. I tried login to AWS console and then upload/delete the content from the folders which should have access, but then as well the same. So, something is wrong with the permission, if AWS allows this sort of things.

Comment: I don't think the way you're writing the IAM policies is valid. See this from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/ - you probably need the `"Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}` sort of bits.

Comment: @serverstackqns could you please answer your own question, to help others in future and so people don't come in and try to help you with your unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for writing a delayed answer: But in my script, change the condition in this way:

```
"Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}
```

Thanks to ceejayoz, for pointing me this error.